# Make database writeable (Azure MS Sql)

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a bacpac file from a read-only database hosted on Azure. When imported to a new server the database is also read-only.

I’ve tried looking for answers with no luck.

How can I change it to a writeable?

Comment: Can you change the attribute on the bacpac and re-deploy? This seems like a hole in the bucket. In order to change the database option, say using `ALTER DATABASE CURRENT`, the database needs to be, well, writable. On-prem it’s a little simpler of course, but in Azure SQL Database, you can’t `USE [master];`...

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like there are any supported ways to change this.  However...

I noticed that the bacpac file is just a zip archive, so I unzipped it.  The basic structure of the folder looks like this:

[image: screenshot of bacpac folder contents]

I then used KDiff to diff two bacpacs of the exact same data - one that was read-write, and one that was read-only.  The main difference of substance was in model.xml:

[image: screenshot of kdiff showing model.xml differences]

So you should be able to remove those two lines* from the bacpac, and then import it, and it will be read-write! I attempted this on my local Developer Edition copy of SQL Server 2016, but got this error message:

> Could not load schema model from package. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac)
>
> The calculated checksum for model.xml in the package C:\Users\username\Desktop\my_database\my_database.bacpac is different from the saved checksum. (Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql)

Which led me to this blog post: [Azure SQL Database Support - Editing a .bacpac file](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2017/08/16/editing-a-bacpac-file/)

> There are times when for whatever reason you just wish you could make a change to a .bacpac file before you import it into Azure.

So I followed the instructions there, running this PowerShell script to generate a new checksum:

```
$modelXmlPath = Read-Host "model.xml file path"

$hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm]::Create("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256CryptoServiceProvider")

$fileStream = new-object System.IO.FileStream ` -ArgumentList @($modelXmlPath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)

$hash = $hasher.ComputeHash($fileStream)

$hashString = ""

Foreach ($b in $hash) { $hashString += $b.ToString("X2") }

$fileStream.Close()

$hashString
```

Then updating the Origin.xml checksum line at the end:

```
<Checksums>
    <Checksum Uri="/model.xml">long checksum number goes here</Checksum>
</Checksums>
```

Zipped all the files again (I used the "Deflate" algorithm in 7-zip), and then imported the database.  It came in perfectly as a normal, read-write database.

*Note: I didn't explicitly enable snapshot isolation, that happens automatically when you set a database to read-only.  Not even Paul White is sure why, so what hope do the rest of us have?  For more, see [Snapshot_isolation_state_desc on a Read only/Stand by Database](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204830/snapshot-isolation-state-desc-on-a-read-only-stand-by-database)

Comment: Wow great I will try this!